# Windows Credential Provider - HTTP Request to authorize from third party

Tags: windows, active-directory, dll

I have created a custom credential provider, but don't know how to authenticate this user from some other server.
I now need to send HTTP Request to the server with the password entered by user, and that server will return AD username/password.
If AD Password is correct, Login the user into the system.

I have asked the same question in more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652456/plugin-to-modify-windows-shortcut-functionality-to-automate-ad-login

Feeling stuck with this, where should I start my code for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I need to handle the communication and logic with any external authentication authorities, as my first step, and then authenticate AD